# Prevent two HTML5 SVGs that are superposed from getting its color darker

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make various svg ellipses, with some transparency, but when they touch in the edges, the color gets darker, is there a way for prevent this behaviour happening, for example by making that part that overlaps of the svg not transparent, or any other solution out of the box?

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask]. An image isn't adequate. Also, 'im' isn't a word.

Comment: Hi, this is colour adition, how would you chose a color between the two? :/

Comment: It would not matter which colour to choose, as far as it is one of the two colors that are overlaping, could be something trivial like the first in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of superimposing partially transparent circles, superimpose solid-colour circles, then make the group of them transparent together.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 150">
  <rect x="50" y="30" width="180" height="100" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="6"/>
  <g opacity="0.5">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="140" cy="50" r="50" fill="purple"/>
    <circle cx="230" cy="50" r="50" fill="blue"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the opacity of the overlapping areas by using a filter. The tableValues below converts anything with an opacity between .2 and .9 back to 0.4.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <defs>
    <filter id="constant-opacity" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 .1 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .9 1"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g filter="url(#constant-opacity)">
  <circle cx="100"cy ="100" r="80" fill="red" fill-opacity=".4"/>
  <circle cx="220"cy ="100" r="80" fill="blue" fill-opacity=".4"/>
  <circle cx="340"cy ="100" r="80" fill="green" fill-opacity=".4"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```